# Searching for stack overflows instead of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search-engine

Sometimes I write code that is not perfect. I know that because my console sometimes looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "blahblahblah" java.lang.StackOverflowError

    at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:124)
    ...
```

Naturally, when this happens, I rush to Google with search phrases like

> getting a stack overflow when I call `foo()` on a `Bar`

As you might expect, this leads to search results like

> baz — is Baz framework a good choice if I need to foo lots of bars? — Stack Overflow

and

> bar — how to foo bars with regexes — Stack Overflow

How can I better search for stack overflow errors without just getting links to stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Okay, yes, strictly speaking, this is off-topic, because it's a question about using search engines, not using Stack Exchange. But it's so close/relevant that I think it's okay... along the same lines as SO allowing questions about IDEs.

Answer (score 9):

While it hasn't always been the best, **using Stack Overflow's search** avoids this problem just fine.  The site can distinguish between itself and its content without difficulty.

Comment: it also accounts for punctuation

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you are asking about general searching outside the SO environment.  Whenever I use a search engine for a specific error, I try to search for the exact error message itself.

In other words, if you search for **"Stack Overflow Error"**, you'll get lots of hits that refer to this site while searching for **"java.lang.StackOverFlowError"** seems more precise.

Comment: I just tested this on Google, and the early hits for `java.lang.StackOverFlowError` were all relevant to the exception, even if the hit was on a stackoverflow.com page.

Answer (score 2):

You could just divide the search space into that within and without Stack Overflow -- first search within SO then head to google to search with "-site:stackoverflow.com". That ought to cover all bases.

Answer (score 1):

Also, and I don't mean this the wrong way, its happened to me plenty of times: Usually when you get that type of error (stack overflow, out of memory, other infinite loop situations), it's because you made a mistake in the code that calls `Bar.foo()` rather than problem with the `Bar` implementation itself. Therefore, it's unlikely that there is a cookie cutter solution available for your problem, anyway.

And, of course, in that case the people at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) are more than happy to help.